# Trouble with XElement Extension Method

Tags: c#, xml, linq, extension-methods

I'm using the below code to pull out info from an XML file. But if node isn't present I get a NullReferenceException error. I thought that wasn't supposed to happen with using LINQ. But I'm very new to LINQ and XML for that matter. So I added an extention method I found from [here](http://tutorialgenius.blogspot.com/2011/06/linqtoxml-safe-element-and-attribute.html). But I still get the error. Can someone tell me what I'm missing please?

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public static class XElementExtensionMethod
{
    public static string ElementValueNull(this XElement element)
    {
        if (element != null)
        {
            return element.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}

namespace XMLReader
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string file = @"c:\users\jim\desktop\XMLData - Copy.xml";
            XElement doc = XElement.Load(file);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            var nodes = from node in doc.Elements("ClaimsSvcRs").Elements("ClaimDownloadRs")
                    select new
                    {
                        ClaimProbableAmount = (string)node.Element("ClaimsDownloadInfo").Element("ClaimsOccurrence").Element("ProbableIncurredAmt").Element("Amt").ElementValueNull()
                    };

        foreach (var node in nodes)
        {
            sb.Append("AMOUNT = ").Append(node.ClaimProbableAmount);
            MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I saw no reference in that "duplicate" that pertain to reading XML.

Comment: the point of referencing that question as a duplicate is that there's only one cause of a `NullReferenceException` - a null reference, which is easily found when debugging but very difficult to find by statically looking at code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly *not* in `ElementValueNull`... it's that one of the earlier `Element` calls is returning null. You're calling an instance method ([`XContainer.Element()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element(v=vs.110).aspx)) and that's a perfectly ordinary instance method - if it's called on a null reference, that will throw an exception just like any other instance method will.

One option to avoid this is to use `Elements` repeatedly instead - that way you'll end up with an empty sequence, instead of a null reference. Use `FirstOrDefault` at the end to get a single `XElement` reference or `null`.

Additionally:

- There's no benefit in using an anonymous type when you've got a single property. Just select the string itself.
- There's no benefit in using a `StringBuilder` when you're calling `ToString()` on each iteration of the loop.

I would write your query as:

```
var amounts = doc.Elements("ClaimsSvcRs").Elements("ClaimDownloadRs")
                 .Select(x => (string) x.Elements("ClaimsDownloadInfo")
                                        .Elements("ClaimsOccurrence")
                                        .Elements("ProbableIncurredAmt")
                                        .Elements("Amt")
                                        .FirstOrDefault() ?? "");
```

(Note the lack of a need for your extension method - the explicit conversion to `string` will return `null` if the input is `null`, and then the null-coalescing operator will take care of using `""` instead of `null`.)

Comment: I actually am using several properties. I omitted them (incorrectly I now see) to shorten my example. Same goes for the StringBuilder. But this helped! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem:

```
ClaimProbableAmount = (string)node.Element("ClaimsDownloadInfo").Element("ClaimsOccurrence").Element("ProbableIncurredAmt").Element("Amt").ElementValueNull()
```

Since you're using `Element()`, you run the risk of getting the NRE.  `Element()` returns the first instance of the named element or null.  You've jumped too far down the rabbit hole.

There are a number of ways you can fix this, change all calls except the last to use `Elements()` instead.  This time it will just return an empty collection if they don't exist.  Or use other approaches such as an equivalent xpath query.

Comment: Are you saying to change the line to ClaimProbableAmount = (string)node.Elements("ClaimsDownloadInfo").Elements("ClaimsOccurrence").Elements("ProbableIncurredAmt").Element("Amt")

Comment: Right. That would be a start.

Answer (score 0):

If any of the parent elements are `null` (i.e. `ClaimsDownloadInfo`, `ClaimsOccurance`, etc), then you'll get a `NullReferenceException`. The `ElementValueNull` extension method won't magically capture that. You'll have to get each element one at a time and confirm that each is not null:

```
var claimsDownloadInfo = node.Element("ClaimsDownloadInfo");
if(claimsDownloadInfo != null)
{
    var claimsOccurance = claimsDownloadInfo.Element("ClaimsOccurrence");
    if(claimsOccurance != null)
    {
        //etc
    }
}
```